# Tkinter object-oriented file dialog?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, self

The following code displays a file dialog, returning a `file_path` string that I may then use to, for example, import a csv directly into a pandas dataframe.

utilities.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


class FileDialog(tk.Tk): # inherits from the tk.Tk class

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.withdraw() # prevents Tkinter window from displaying

    def open(self):
        return fd.askopenfilename()

    def saveas(self):
        return fd.asksaveasfilename()
```

main.py:

```
import utilities as util


file_path = util.FileDialog().open()
```

I am teaching myself advanced programming concepts such as inheritance and the self keyword, and am requesting feedback on whether I am applying these ideas correctly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what you post correct, but don't use multiple `tk.Tk`, prefers every tkinter app have one `Tk` class for main window and multiple `tk.TopLevel` for sub windows in main window.

Comment: Shihab, does your comment still apply if I'm not looking to display any Tkinter windows? Just looking to have a lightweight dialog for selecting files.